# How to dynamically bind a dynamically imported type

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am trying to have templates automagically wired to an inversifyjs container but whatever I try it's not working. Please help?

```
private templates = [
    {file: './component.html.tpl', obj: 'HtmlTemplate'},
    {file: './component.tpl.ts', obj: 'ComponentTemplate'}
];
private container = new Container();
bind(){
    // original and working code 
    // this.container.bind<ITemplate>('HtmlTemplate').to(HtmlTemplate);
    // this.container.bind<ITemplate>('ComponentTemplate').to(ComponentTemplate);
    this.templates.forEach(template => {
        import(template.file).then(mod => {
            console.log(mod.default, template);
            // is this correct (seems to work) => 
            this.container.bind<ITemplate>(template.obj).to(mod.default);
            console.log('bound =>', mod.default);
        });
    });
}
```

and files ./component.html.tpl

```
@injectable() export default class HtmlTemplate implements ITemplate { ... }
```

and ./component.ts.tpl

```
@injectable() export default class ComponentTemplate implements ITemplate { ... }
```

Which logs completely as expected to the console:

```
[Function: HtmlTemplate] { file: './component.html.tpl', obj: 'HtmlTemplate' }
[Function: ComponentTemplate] { file: './component.tpl.ts', obj: 'ComponentTemplate' }
```

But I really expected the code in the foreach statement:

```
this.container.bind<ITemplate>(template.obj).to(mod.default);
```

to be equivalent to this:

```
this.container.bind<HtmlTemplate>('HtmlTemplate').to(HtmlTemplate);
this.container.bind<ComponentTemplate>('ComponentTemplate').to(ComponentTemplate);
```

but when I try to resolve it in an other loop:

```
this.templates.forEach(template => {
    const tpl = this.container.get<ITemplate>(template.obj);
...
```

it throws an error:

```
Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier HtmlTemplate
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does `console.log(mod.default, template)` work? And where exactly does it throw an error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be helpful here. `import(template.file)` is asynchronous. There may be race condition. Try to use `let mod = require(template.file)` instead and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, works console.log(mod.default, template), the generated js uses require just as you suggested. No, race conditions, the modules resolve their default exports just as expected. Updated the question to reflect where it throws the error!

Comment: `import()` returns a promise, which is asynchronous. It causes one-tick delay. If 'other loop' occurs synchronously, that's the issue.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why "I added import(template.file).then(mod => { ..."  according to my knowledge the callback code will only execute when the promised is resolved. and the working console.log should be prove of that since its prints out the resolved class "[Function: HtmlTemplate]"  prefectly. So, I think that's the problem but I might be wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest to just place console.log into `this.templates.forEach(template => {` loop and check if console.log from import() occurs earlier.

Comment: scoping issues I suspect. when the bind and resolve are in the same function scope as the dynamic import, it works as expected but when the resolve is in another method in the scope of the instance sharing a container, the types dont resolve. Somehow the container looses its  scope bindings?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible. I would suspect race condition unless proven otherwise, that's most probable cause. Can you provide a way to replicate the problem? A repo, etc.

Comment: Setup a repo I have been fighting with all day https://github.com/wendellmva/ioc-problem.git

Comment: I quickly checked it. Yes, there's race condition. Promises aren't chained and result in uncontrollable control flow. Try to chain Promise.all with `.catch(() => { debugger })` and you'll see that the error happens before widget items have a chance to be bound. Just replace all import() with require. Node typings need to be set up for that. At least I see no errors. https://www.sendspace.com/file/50cbdw . Promise constructors will likely be removed later too (they are antipatterns any way).

Comment: I didn't remove procesImport because it doesn't affect anything (it's synchronous despite `async`), but it should be removed as well, it's callback-based and doesn't serve a good purpose with `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has problems with control flow. There are promises that aren't chained, which is antipattern. This results in inefficient error handling and race conditions.

Each and every promise should be chained. The use of `forEach` is discouraged in ES6 for several reasons, one of them is that it requires additional actions to work with promises and doesn't work well with generators and `async` functions. The code can take most of `async` functions and be refactored to make control flow clean and efficient:

```
async bind(){
    for (const template of this.templates)
       const mod = await import(template.file);
       this.container.bind<ITemplate>(template.obj).to(mod.default);
    }
}
```

The code that uses `bind` should chain it and avoid promise construction antipatterns:

```
async bind() {
    // binding for when the widget is needed;
    for (const component of this.components)
        component.widget = this.container.get<Widget>(component.name);
        if(component.widget) {
            await component.widget.configure();
            await component.widget.bind();
        } else {
            console.error(`widget ${component.name} not resolved`);
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

A more efficient way is to discard asynchronous initialization routine, because the only thing that requires it is dynamic `import()`. `import()` promises can be replaced with synchronous `require` statements, `import()` falls back to `require` in Node.js any way.

Comment: You had it right in your first answer, changed the import to require and the dynamic imports worked. Wish I had listened and understood yesterday. Could have saved myself two whole days.