# Instantiate object after promisified import

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, import

I am struggling to instantiate object from dynamically imported classes. Basically I have some plugins which kinda look like this:

```
export interface IPlugin {
    compile(logEvent: LogEventInfo): string;
}

export class DatePlugin implements IPlugin {
    public compile(logEvent: LogEventInfo): string {
        const date: Date = new Date();
        return `${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}`;
    }
}
```

In another file I want to dynamically crawl a folder, load all source files and instantiate them. I saw that `import(...).then()` can return a loaded object however in my case it returns the class and my object creation starts looking very ugly:

```
public async loadPlugins(): Promise<void> {
    // ...
    await Promise.all(pluginFiles.map(async (pluginFile: string): Promise<void> => {
        const pluginFilePath: string = path.join(pluginsFolder, pluginFile);
        import(pluginFilePath).then((plugin: any): void => {
            const obj: IPlugin = (new plugin[Object.keys(plugin)[0]]() as IPlugin;
            // ...
        });
    }));
}
```

Isn't there any better way to instantiate all those classes when loading them?

Comment: What should happen with obj exactly?

Comment: @estus In the particular `loadPlugins` method I will be storing all `obj` in a map which I will access in another function to call those `IPlugin.compile` methods dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import()` promises aren't chained, this is a mistake similar to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50358563/3731501) that may result in problems with error handling and race conditions.

`map` shares a common potential problem with [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378002/3731501). It's used only to provide promises to wait for them, but not actual values. Since the purpose of `async` function call is to get class instance, it's reasonable to map `pluginFile` input to `obj` output value if it's supposed to be stored then - or `compile` result if it isn't:

```
public async loadPlugins(): Promise<...> {
  const plugins = await Promise.all(pluginFiles.map(async (pluginFile: string): Promise<IPlugin> => {
    const pluginFilePath: string = path.join(pluginsFolder, pluginFile);
    const pluginExports = await import(pluginFilePath);

    // preferably pluginExports.default export to not rely on keys order
    const Plugin: { new(): IPlugin } = Object.values(pluginExports)[0];
    return new Plugin();
  }));
  ...
}
```

The only real benefit that `import` provides here is that it's future-proof, it can seamlessly be used *natively* in Node.js with *third-party* ES modules (.mjs) files. Since TypeScript is used any way and uses `require` for ES module imports under the hood, it may be reasonable to discard asynchronous routine and use `require` synchronously instead of `import` for dynamic imports:

```
public loadPlugins(): <...> {
  const plugins = pluginFiles.map((pluginFile: string): IPlugin => {
    const pluginFilePath: string = path.join(pluginsFolder, pluginFile);
    const pluginExports = require(pluginFilePath);

     // preferably pluginExports.default export to not rely on keys order
    const Plugin: { new(): IPlugin } = Object.values(pluginExports)[0];
    return new Plugin();
  }));
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am curious after you just mentioned I might as well just use `require` synchronously (which would simplify a lot for me as async methods can be a pain) what would you suggest, how should I require and instantiate the classes in the plugin files with using `require` instead of `import`?

Comment: Added the example. As you can see, once async/await is heavily used to provide sync-like control flow, it's fairly similar. I'd just go with it.

Comment: You have a minor typo as it need to be `{ new(): IPlugin }` but it finally works and even synchronized.